# How to filter out certain dates in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to display all data from dates except for the 1st, 15th and last day of each month.

Tried querying with this (dates left out on purpose for this question):

`BETWEEN date 'YYYY-MM-DD' AND date 'YYYY-MM-DD' WHERE date NOT ((BETWEEN 'YYYY-MM-DD' AND 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND DAY(date) IN (1,15,31))`

Getting an error and also this doesn't take into account for the months that don't have 31 days. Wasn't sure how to check for that.

Comment: Please put the exact error you get into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking:

```
where extract(day from date) not in (1, 15, extract(day from last_day(date)))
```

Or, an interesting approach is:

```
where extract(day from date + interval '1' day) not in (2, 16, 1)
```

Comment: @Jaren So provide a full statement. As per your current question you have two `where` clauses in one statement which are obviously not allowed.

Comment: @Jaren So how does it relate to the answer (there's a complete syntactically correct where clause in it)? The answer doesn't contain incorrect syntax, so no one can provide you *entire* syntactically correct statement until you provide us your current code